# What benefit was there by replacing “chart” with “tabulate”, then with “tally” in the NYT headline: “Bank charted business linked to China hiring.”?

Tags: meaning, writing-style

I was drawn to the changes of the headline of today’s New York Times’ article reporting JPMorgan Chase established a program to hire a lot of sons and daughters of Chinese   dignitaries.

The headline I saw first in this morning in its online edition was “Bank **charted** business linked to China hiring.” It was “Bank **tabulated** business –” in 10 minutes later, and now the final version (6:40 PM ET) is “Bank **tallied** business linked to China hiring” followed by the lead-copy:

> “Confidential documents offer the most detailed account yet of
>   JPMorgan Chase’s “Sons and Daughters” hiring program in China, which
>   has been at the center of a federal bribery investigation.” 
>   http://dealbook.nytimes.com/2013/12/07/bank-tabulated-business-linked-to-china-hiring/?hp

I understand “chart “and “tally” are different in meaning. But I wonder what is the intent of deliberately changing the verb in a short headline from “chart” to “tabulate” to “tally” in a few minutes to a few hours?

Isn’t the headline saying the same thing after all, or is it making any improvement of wording or articulation by making these changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intended meanings of the three formulations (using 'charted', 'tabulated', and 'tallied') are isomorphic.  Roughly:

J.P. Morgan entered in a tally (chart/table) the business resulting from the hiring (of the offspring of Chinese leaders).

For me comprehensibility improves from zero to about 0.9.  Perhaps 'charted' is too ambiguous?

-- Mats (mr249@cornell.edu)